# Reading URL from json file by using batch script

Tags: json, batch-file, batch-processing

I am reading a config json file through batchscript and creating variables dynamically.

Content of json file is given below

```
{ 
"ApplicationId":"c2b925c2-e5c9-4534-b855-43534",
"ApplicationProcess":"453453-ca1c-4735-806a-45345",
"VersionComponentId":"4533-35d2-4f0c-bb7a-rtert",
"uDClientFolder":"/udclient/",
"FID":"myId",
"FAuthToken":"mypassword",
"uDeployUrl":"https://myurl:8445",
"outPutDir":"..\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\OutPut",
}
```

Batch script to read variables is given below

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:, " %%a in (' find ":" ^< ".\%jsonConfigFile%" ') do (


   set a=%%~a: =%
   set b=%%~b: =%
   set "%%~a=%%~b"
)
```

Here i am facing two problems.
1. Unable to read uDeployUrl because it contains ://. I am getting only https part of the url.
2. If my json contains space before the keyname like
    "Application":"value"
Then variable name will also contain space in it's name. So how can i remove starting space from variable name

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('find ":" "%jsonConfigFile%"') do set "%%~a=%%~b
```

- Use `tokens=1*` to get everything after `:` into `%%b`
- Use `~` prefix to strip the surrounding quotes from `%%a` and the opening quote from `%%b`
- Since the last quote in `%%b` is followed by `,` it won't be removed but we can simply enclose the entire `set` assignment into doublequotes by prefixing it with one doublequote so that the final assignment will be for example `set "uDeployUrl=https://myurl:8445",` - the last comma will be ignored.
- `find`'s second parameter is a file name so no need to use input redirection via `<`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your config json file is invalid. The backslashes in the "outPutDir" object's value need to be escaped. The valid json would therefore be:

```
{
  "ApplicationId": "c2b925c2-e5c9-4534-b855-43534",
  "ApplicationProcess": "453453-ca1c-4735-806a-45345",
  "VersionComponentId": "4533-35d2-4f0c-bb7a-rtert",
  "uDClientFolder": "/udclient/",
  "FID": "myId",
  "FAuthToken": "mypassword",
  "uDeployUrl": "https://myurl:8445",
  "outPutDir": "..\\Binaries\\_PublishedWebsites\\OutPut"
}
```

I'd suggest using a proper JSON interpreter like [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
xidel -s config.json -e "$json() ! eval(x'{.}:=$json/{.}')[0]"
ApplicationId := c2b925c2-e5c9-4534-b855-43534
ApplicationProcess := 453453-ca1c-4735-806a-45345
VersionComponentId := 4533-35d2-4f0c-bb7a-rtert
uDClientFolder := /udclient/
FID := myId
FAuthToken := mypassword
uDeployUrl := https://myurl:8445
outPutDir := ..\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\OutPut
```

Xidel opens 'config.json'. By default `$json` represents the json's content. `$json()` holds a sequence of all the object's attributes:

```
ApplicationId
ApplicationProcess
VersionComponentId
uDClientFolder
FID
FAuthToken
uDeployUrl
outPutDir
```

These strings are fed to (`!`) the [eval-function](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-eval) and the output can be seen above.

To actually export these variables in Batch:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel -s config.json -e "$json() ! eval(x'{.}:=$json/{.}')[0]" --output-format^=cmd') DO %%A
SET ApplicationId=c2b925c2-e5c9-4534-b855-43534
SET ApplicationProcess=453453-ca1c-4735-806a-45345
SET VersionComponentId=4533-35d2-4f0c-bb7a-rtert
SET uDClientFolder=/udclient/
SET FID=myId
SET FAuthToken=mypassword
SET uDeployUrl=https://myurl:8445
SET outPutDir=..\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\OutPut
```